# How does one bind a complex object to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have a class that follows the form:

```
public class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set; }
    public List<Cheezburger> Cheezbugers { get; private set; }
};

public class Cheezburger
{
    public int PattyCount { get; set; }
    public bool CanHaz { get; set; }
};
```

I want to be able to display a `List` of Cats this in a `DataGridView` as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name     | Description  |  PattyCount | CanHaz   | PattyCount   | CanHaz  | etc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Felix    | Classic Cat  |  1          | true     | 3            | false   | etc
| Garfield | Fat,Lazy Cat |  2          | false    | 7            | true    | etc
```

And so on... The goal being to list out all the `Cat`'s `Cheezbuger`s in the same row. If you simply try binding the list of `Cat`s you won't get this behavior.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do a do a complex binding of source between the `DataGridView` and the individual items in the list of `Cats.Cheezbugers`. For what its worth, I know for sure that each `Cat` in the list has the same number of `Cheezbuger`s in its list.

**Edit**:

I am aware that [DataGridView complex binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891644/datagridview-complex-binding) asks the same question, but the accepted answer works only if I know how many items are in the list ahead of time, and that is not the case. All I know is that all the lists will have the same length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't just a 'complex binding' this is a *Pivot*, where you are wanting to transform detail repeating data (the list o' cheezburgers) to a single row, and that row has an undetermined number of columns.

I believe your best option here is to write a custom serializer that will allow you to transform your data into rows in an xml datatable and then bind to that. Since your column count is going to be inconsistent xml will be more forgiving, though I am not sure how the DataGridView will handle it.

**EDIT FOLLOWS**
Since I did not 'know' how the DataGridView would handle the XML DataTable I decided to write it up and test it. I works how I expected, and I believe how you will want.

1. Here are your cat & cheezburger classes (slightly modified)

   ```
   public class Cat
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public List<Cheezburger> Cheezbugers { get; private set; }

       public void AddCheezburger(Cheezburger cheezburger)
       {
           if (this.Cheezbugers == null)
               this.Cheezbugers = new List<Cheezburger>();
           this.Cheezbugers.Add(cheezburger); 
       }
   };

   public class Cheezburger
   {
       public int PattyCount { get; set; }
       public bool CanHaz { get; set; }
   };
   ```
2. Then you need to create simple form with two buttons "bind to object" (button1) and "bind to datatable" (button2), with a DataGridView anchored to the bottom. and code up the form like:

//in the editor this next line is in the codeblock, once I save it it isn't..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cats.Add(new Cat() { Name = "Felix", Description = "Classic Cat" });
        cats.Add(new Cat() { Name = "Garfield", Description = "Fat,Lazy" });
        cats.Add(new Cat() { Name = "Tom", Description = "Wanna-Be-Mouser" });
        cats[0].AddCheezburger(new Cheezburger() { CanHaz = true, PattyCount = 1 });
        cats[0].AddCheezburger(new Cheezburger() { CanHaz = false, PattyCount = 3 });
        cats[1].AddCheezburger(new Cheezburger() { CanHaz = false, PattyCount = 2 });
        cats[1].AddCheezburger(new Cheezburger() { CanHaz = true, PattyCount = 7 });
        cats[1].AddCheezburger(new Cheezburger() { CanHaz = true, PattyCount = 99 });
        cats[2].AddCheezburger(new Cheezburger() { CanHaz = true, PattyCount = 5 });
        cats[2].AddCheezburger(new Cheezburger() { CanHaz = false, PattyCount = 14 });

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = cats;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = serializeCats(cats);
    }

    private DataTable serializeCats(List<Cat> cats)
    {

        DataTable returnTable = new DataTable("Cats");
        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description"));
        int setID = 1;
        foreach (Cat cat in cats)
        {
            //If the row requires more columns than are present then add additional columns
            int totalColumnsRequired = (cat.Cheezbugers.Count * 2) + 2;

            while (returnTable.Columns.Count < totalColumnsRequired)
            {
                returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Can Haz " + setID.ToString()));
                returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Patty Count " + setID.ToString()));
                setID++;
            }
            returnTable.AcceptChanges();
            DataRow row = returnTable.NewRow();
            row[0] = cat.Name;
            row[1] = cat.Description;
            int cbi = 2; //cheezburger index
            foreach (Cheezburger cheezburger in cat.Cheezbugers)
            {
                row[cbi] = cheezburger.CanHaz;
                cbi++;
                row[cbi] = cheezburger.PattyCount;
                cbi++;
            }

            returnTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return returnTable;
    }
}
```

Do not attempt to predefine the DataGridView columns, they will be created dynamically based on the data source. Binding to the list of cats will get you two columns (name/description) Binding to the DataTable gets 8 columns, name & description + 6 columns of cheezburger info, lined up as (I believe) you want.
[image: Cats Haz Cheezeburgers]

Comment: Awesome answer and well presented.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, I think what you're asking is how to display the list of `Cheezbugers` items for each cat.

One way conceptually to accomplish this is to bind the `Cheezbugers` property to a `Repeater` with a custom column template in the grid. In other words nest a repeater in a custom template grid column and bind it there. You could use a list item pattern or other format to present the list of Cheezbugers. It would support any number of items in the list.

**EDIT:** I just realized you are developing in windows forms, not asp.net. There is an equivalent or reasonable equivalent to the repeater in forms - [DataRepeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx). Could possible meet your needs. Idea above is the same.

Comment: Yes, you're understanding my question correctly. Never even heard of a `Repeater` before, gonna go read up on it.

Comment: I edited the answer after realizing your working with windows forms, not asp.net. The repeater approach could still meet your needs (see answer).