# How to manually populate control data binding datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, manual

I'm new to vb.net. I'm used to do things the old school way (VB6).

Is there a way to manually populate a datagridview? In the old way (VB6) I populate a listview by adding columns manually and loop to a recordset to add the rows.

For example what if I have this command (storedproc).

`"Select OrderID, ProductName, Qty, SellingPrice, CustomerName FROM tblOrders".`

What if I only need to show `OrderID, ProductName and SellingPrice?`

Is there a way to manually add columns OrderID, ProductName, SellingPrice to the datagridview and loop to the result set to add the rows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To add column to DataTable

```
Dim MyTable as New DataTable
Dim dc As DataColumn

dc = New DataColumn
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
dc.ColumnName = "OrderID"
MyTable.Columns.Add(dc)

dc = New DataColumn
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
dc.ColumnName = "ProductName"
MyTable.Columns.Add(dc)

dc = New DataColumn
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
dc.ColumnName = "SellingPrice"
MyTable.Columns.Add(dc)
```

So, you can set MyTable as Datasource

```
DataGridview1.DataSource = MyTable
```

To add rows .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @user2059064 .. It's added

Comment: My data is from a storedprocedure. I'm not using direct table access.  What I need is how to programatically populate a datagridview (manually add columns and rows).

Comment: You can add the columns and rows to your DataTable instance that you populate from the stored proc like how @matzone shows in his answer.

Comment: I now understand why you suggested using Datatable. I'm new to .net It did not occur to me its possible to create a table in memory. I can now see it's usefulness. Populate Datatable. Set the datasource of datagridview to the Datatable. In theory I somewhat understand the concept of datatable. I can edit the data in memory and when i'm ready I can update the database using the datatable. I'm I correct? I will look more into this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the strange solution. If your query will never changes (i.e first column is forever "OrderID", second is "ProductName" etc.) you could hide unwanted columns.

```
DataGridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False       'hiding 3rd column
DataGridView1.Columns(4).Visible = False       'hiding 5th column
```

Comment: Just as a hint: This will probably work for the question of the OP above but will fail for [binding complex objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955188/how-does-one-bind-a-complex-object-to-a-datagridview/5955394#5955394).

Answer (score 0):

I got this code from a book. This code is close enough. At least I can configure the format and alignment of a Column.

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Configuration

    Public Class Form1

        Dim objConnection As New  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyDatabase").ConnectionString)
        Dim objDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnection
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT authors.au_lname, authors.au_fname, titles.title, titles.price FROM authors INNER JOIN titleauthor ON authors.au_id = titleauthor.au_id INNER JOIN titles ON titleauthor.title_id = titles.title_id ORDER BY authors.au_lname, authors.au_fname"
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        objConnection.Open()
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "authors")
        objConnection.Close()

        grdAuthorsTitles.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        grdAuthorsTitles.DataSource = objDataSet
        grdAuthorsTitles.DataMember = "authors"

        Dim objAlignRightCellStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle
        objAlignRightCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight

        Dim objAlernatingCellStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()
        objAlernatingCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        grdAuthorsTitles.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = objAlernatingCellStyle

        Dim objCurrencyCellStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()
        objCurrencyCellStyle.Format = "c"
        objCurrencyCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight

        grdAuthorsTitles.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Last Name"
        grdAuthorsTitles.Columns(1).HeaderText = "First Name"
        grdAuthorsTitles.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Book Title"
        grdAuthorsTitles.Columns(2).Width = 225

        grdAuthorsTitles.Columns("price").HeaderCell.Value = "Retail Price"
        grdAuthorsTitles.Columns("price").HeaderCell.Style = objAlignRightCellStyle
        grdAuthorsTitles.Columns("price").DefaultCellStyle = objCurrencyCellStyle

        objDataAdapter = Nothing
        objConnection = Nothing
        objCurrencyCellStyle = Nothing
        objAlignRightCellStyle = Nothing
        objAlernatingCellStyle = Nothing

    End Sub

End Class
```