# C# Bind List<object> to DataGridView

Tags: c#, list, object, datagridview

I've got a question regarding binding an object list to a DataGridView in C#. First I'll give the code sample:

```
public class RoomToImport
{
    public string Roomnumber { get; set; }
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<CustomParameter> ParameterList;
}

public class CustomParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

After gathering the data, I have a List with all rooms, which have a dynamic amount of parameters stored inside. To clarify, a user can set a certain amount of parameters in another settings form. This can vary from time to time, but the set amount will be the same for all rooms.

When I bind the list to the DataGridView, I only get to see the Roomnumber, UniqueID and the Status, which makes sense:

```
SortableBindingList<RoomToImport> = new SortableBindingList<RoomToImport>(RoomsList);
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(sortableBindingList, null);
dgvChanges.DataSource = bindingSource;
dgvChanges.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

My question is: is there a way I can also show the custom parameters as a new column, with it's name property as column header and it's value property as row value?

Comment: i think  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955188/how-does-one-bind-a-complex-object-to-a-datagridview) will help you

Comment: Can you make ParameterList a property (and give CustomParameter a ToString method)? Then you should get one more column showing the tostring result..

Comment: Thanks styx! That did the trick.